# Saving python dictionary (or JSON?) as CSV

Tags: python, json, dictionary, google-search-api

I have been trying to save the output from Google Search Console API as a CSV File. Initially, I was using sys.stdout to save what was print from the sample code they had provided. However, on the third or so attempt, I started receiving this error:

```
File "C:\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\uff1a' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>
```

After that I tried switching to using Pandas to csv funtion. The result is not what I had hoped for but is at least closer:

```
> ,rows,responseAggregationType
0,"{'keys': ['amp pwa'], 'clicks': 1, 'impressions': 4, 'ctr': 0.25, 'position': 7.25}",byProperty
1,"{'keys': ['convert desktop site to mobile'], 'clicks': 1, 'impressions': 2, 'ctr': 0.5, 'position': 1.5}",byProperty
```

I'm very new to python but I figure it has something to do with the output from the API pull not being quite the standard dict object format.

I also tried using the csv.write function (I deleted that code before coming here so I don't have an example) but the result was the same unable to encode issues as from sys.stdout.

Here is the code that prints the output exactly as I need it, I just need to be able to save it somewhere where I can use it in a spreadsheet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('property_uri', type=str,
                       help=('Site or app URI to query data for (including '
                             'trailing slash).'))
argparser.add_argument('start_date', type=str,
                       help=('Start date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))
argparser.add_argument('end_date', type=str,
                       help=('End date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))


def main(argv):
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'searchconsole', 'v1', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')

  # Get top 10 queries for the date range, sorted by click count, descending.
  request = {
      'startDate': flags.start_date,
      'endDate': flags.end_date,
      'dimensions': ['query'],
      'rowLimit': 10
  }
  response = execute_request(service, flags.property_uri, request)
  print_table(response, 'Top Queries')


def execute_request(service, property_uri, request):
  """Executes a searchAnalytics.query request.

  Args:
    service: The searchconsole service to use when executing the query.
    property_uri: The site or app URI to request data for.
    request: The request to be executed.

  Returns:
    An array of response rows.
  """
  return service.searchanalytics().query(
      siteUrl=property_uri, body=request).execute()


def print_table(response, title):
  """Prints out a response table.

  Each row contains key(s), clicks, impressions, CTR, and average position.

  Args:
    response: The server response to be printed as a table.
    title: The title of the table.
  """
  print('\n --' + title + ':')
  
  if 'rows' not in response:
    print('Empty response')
    return

  rows = response['rows']
  row_format = '{:<20}' + '{:>20}' * 4
  print(row_format.format('Keys', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'CTR', 'Position'))
  for row in rows:
    keys = ''
    # Keys are returned only if one or more dimensions are requested.
    if 'keys' in row:
      keys = u','.join(row['keys']).encode('utf-8').decode()
    print(row_format.format(
        keys, row['clicks'], row['impressions'], row['ctr'], row['position']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Here's the output as I want it, but comma separated:

```
Keys                              Clicks         Impressions                 CTR            Position
amp pwa                                1                   4                0.25                7.25
convert desktop site to mobile                   1                   2                 0.5                 1.5
```

And here is what printing just the result object results in:

```
{'rows': [{'keys': ['amp pwa'], 'clicks': 1, 'impressions': 4, 'ctr': 0.25, 'position': 7.25}, {'keys': ['convert desktop site to mobile'], 'clicks': 1, 'impressions': 2, 'ctr': 0.5, 'position': 1.5}], 'responseAggregationType': 'byProperty'}
```

I hope I have included enough info, I tried every solution recommended here and on other sites before asking a question. It just seems like an oddly formatted json/dictionary object.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

### Update, Solution:

Adjused output code to be:

```
  import csv
  with open("out.csv", "w", encoding="utf8", newline='') as f:
      rows = response['rows']
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      headers = ["Keys", "Clicks", "Impressions", "CTR", "Position"]
      writer.writerow(headers)
      
      for row in rows:
        keys = ''
        # Keys are returned only if one or more dimensions are requested.
        if 'keys' in row:
          keys = u','.join(row['keys']).encode('utf-8').decode()
          # Looks like your data has the keys in lowercase
        writer.writerow([keys, row['clicks'], row['impressions'], row['ctr'], row['position']])
```

Comment: "Initially, I was using sys.stdout to save what was print from the sample code they had provided." What is printed by `print_table` isn't valid CSV data; it's a nicely formatted representation of the table intended to look right in the terminal. Anyway, what happened when you tried converting just the `result['rows']` to CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just be the encoding of the output file that's the problem.

It looks like the rows you get from the response are a series of dict-like objects, so this should work:

```
import csv
with open("out.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    headers = ["Keys", "Clicks", "Impressions", "CTR", "Position"]
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(
            [
                ", ".join(row.get("keys", [])),
                row["clicks"],
                row["impressions"],
                row["ctr"],
                row["postition"],
            ]
        )
```

The writer object accepts a number of arguments to control line separators and quoting in the output csv. Check the [module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) for details.

Comment: This helped so much! You saved me from having to tell my boss 8 hours went nowhere.

Comment: However, now the output looks like: 
Keys,Clicks,Impressions,CTR,Position

['amp pwa'],1,4,0.25,7.25

['convert desktop site to mobile'],1,2,0.5,1.5

Which is a vast improvement, and easily cleaned in sheets later. I tried reproducing some of the code from the original print statement 
      for row in rows:
          # Looks like your data has the keys in lowercase
          writer.writerow([row[field.lower()] for field in headers])
          if 'keys' in row:
            keys = u','.join(row['keys']).encode('utf-8').decode()

But no luck, same exact output as from your code.

Comment: I've updated the answer to select each output field explicitly instead of using the list comprehension - it makes it clearer how you'd alter one of them when processing the rows.

Comment: Thanks Malcolm. I'm having trouble with the output for more than one 'key' having double quotes around it. I posted in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350335/removing-a-character-from-a-response-row-in-python) to avoid going too far into the comments here.

Comment: That's what's expected with the csv format you're using though - the field delimiter [,] is part of the keys field so the field gets quoted with the quotechar ["]. You could change the delimiter to another character that's not part of your data to avoid quoting - replace it with a tab and you'll have a tsv file instead for example.