# Removing a Character from a Response Row in Python

Tags: dictionary, google-api, google-search-console

Related to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278684/saving-python-dictionary-or-json-as-csv/68279061?noredirect=1#comment120702567_68279061)

I'm trying to save a dictionary response as a csv file. I've gotten 90% of the way to the format that I want thanks to [Malcolm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133463/malcolm)

Here's the writer code I'm using:

```
import csv
with open("out.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    headers = ["Keys", "Clicks", "Impressions", "CTR", "Position"]
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(
            [
                ", ".join(row.get("keys", [])),
                row["clicks"],
                row["impressions"],
                row["ctr"],
                row["postition"],
            ]
        )
```

And it works perfectly unless I select more than one "key"

The output for one 'key':

```
Keys,Clicks,Impressions,CTR,Position
amp pwa,1,4,0.25,7.25
```

The output if two are selected:

```
Keys,Clicks,Impressions,CTR,Position
"amp pwa,MOBILE",1,2,0.5,5.5
```

The keys are dimensions passed to Google Search Console API using their code:

```
request = {
      'startDate': flags.start_date,
      'endDate': flags.end_date,
      'dimensions': ['query'],
      'rowLimit': 20
      
  }
```

I'm working on writing another program that would go through all the resulting CSV files (I'm running more than one response at a time) and remove all the double quotes.

Thought you all might have a more elegant solution than strong arming it that way.

Very new to Python and coding in general so If I've overlooked something obvious I apologize. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following
`", ".join(str(row.get("keys", [])).replace('"',''))`
but that makes the results like a comma after every character

I also tried editing the writer to include a include a quoting argument:
`writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

That resulted in this error: `_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`

I tried using both \0 and '' as escape characters but it gives me the same error

using \n or ',' messes up the formatting even more.

Comment: I've always associated the csv format as keeping data aligned in fields, like a spreadsheet. Is this why you're wanting csv output? Because if it is, then I don't understand why you want the quotes removed from the keys field - that would result in data no longer being aligned with your headers.

Comment: That's a good question. In this instance it is because the keys  column is what the search console API is aggregating by. 
Sometimes its aggregated by date or page and sometimes both. If I could get there to be two keys columns I suppose that would work. 
maybe like keys[1] and keys [2] but then I'm not sure what would happen if there were only one key. I'll give that a whirl and see what comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [Malcom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133463/malcolm) question I realized I was going about this all wrong. I should be splitting out the column and adding to it instead of replacing it. Here's the solution I came up with

```
  import csv

  filename = title + ".csv"

  
  with open(p/filename, "w", encoding="utf8", newline='') as f:
    rows = response["rows"]
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    headers = ["Keys", "Clicks", "Impressions", "CTR", "Position", "date", "page", "device", "query"]
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in rows:
        dimensions = row["keys"]
        writer.writerow(
            [
                ", ".join(row.get("keys", [])),
                row["clicks"],
                row["impressions"],
                row["ctr"],
                row["position"],
                dimensions[0], dimensions[1], dimensions[2], dimensions[3]
            ]
        )
```

I just needed to set "keys" to another un *variable?* (list maybe) and then call the items out as additional fields when saving the csv.